# Combine two SUMIF formulas into a single formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have two SUMIF formulas. Both do what I expect them to
but I need to combine them together.

The first formula gets all values from Column I where a specific word (eg "Word") is written in Column F:

```
=sumif(F:F; "Word"; I:I)
```

The second formula gets all values from Column I where the dates in Column B are equal to or greater than January 1, 2024.

```
=sumif(B:B; ">=2024-01-01"; I:I)
```

I want to combine these two formulas. I tried several approaches from Google searches but keep getting errors saying that my attempt contains too many arguments.

How can I combine these two formulas?

Comment: Try [sumifs()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496).

Comment: @doubleunary could you elaborate? Currently using Sheets as a last resort, so not well versed in it's syntax

Comment: I added [an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/175212/197518). @doubleunary linked his comment to the relevant function support page as I have in [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/175212/197518). If you have future similar syntax questions first review the relevant support page as they include both the syntax as well as real-world examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Your Formula with SUMIFS 
=SUMIFS(I:I; F:F; "Word"; B:B; ">=2024-01-01")
```

[SUMIFS Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)

```
# Syntax
=SUMIFS(sum_range; criteria_range1; criterion1; [criteria_range2; ...]; [criterion2;‎ ...])

# North America
=SUMIFS(sum_range, ‎criteria_range1,‎ criterion1,‎ [criteria_range2,‎ ...],‎ [criterion2,‎ ...])
```

[SUMIF Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)

```
# Syntax
=SUMIF(range; criterion; [sum_range])

# North America
=SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])
```

Comment: Found the issue, i used SUMIF instead of SUMIFS... the missing s is what was wrong.